# How do I Use .times for floats?

Tags: ruby, methods

I am trying to use **.times** in ruby for floats... but when i try it shows this error:

```
/home/habniss/Desktop/Sublime/Platformer/Player.rb:2:in `LikeAllPlayerStuff': 
undefined method `times' for 0.5:Float (NoMethodError)

@y_sp.times do
     ^^^^^^
```

Here is my code:

```rb
@y_sp.times do
     @player.y += @y_sp
end
@y_sp += 0.2
```

How do i use .times for floats?
(If It is even possible....)

Comment: What would it mean to run a loop a fraction of an iteration? Only run some of the code inside the loop?!

Comment: Yeah?...........

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @IssUseless this seems to be a follow-up question to our conversation. That approach only works for whole numbers.

Comment: Do you make games? **NOBODY AWNSERS** Also i am making a game

Comment: @IssUseless You asked a simple question. *"How do i use .times for floats?"* to which is the answer is: *"You can't. It is logically impossible"*. People are inquiring as to your motivation so that may be we can assist with the actual problem and not just the symptomatic outcome. If you do not wish to answer that question that is your prerogative as the OP; however I would recommend using a slightly more civil approach in the future. Remember you came here to ask for help.

Comment: @IssUseless your question is a so-called [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking about the problem you are trying to solve (collision detection of two rectangles), you ask about your attempted solution (using `times` with floats). But since you can't use `times` with floats and because you didn't give any additional information, the only answer is "you can't" which is probably frustrating. You should take some time to [write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) – explain what you are trying to do, describe the problem, show some code (not too much).

Comment: In the meantime, this might help: [Celeste and TowerFall Physics](https://maddythorson.medium.com/celeste-and-towerfall-physics-d24bd2ae0fc5) – it explains the physics approach behind the two 2D platformers [Celeste](http://www.celestegame.com/) and [TowerFall](http://www.towerfall-game.com/). (e.g. moving objects 1px at a time to detect collisions)

Comment: @IssUseless Yes, I've made games (multiple Sega platforms, 3DO, PC, cross-platform), relevancy unclear. Executing a loop "1.337 times" doesn't make much sense. You can exit loops early from within the loop, add a value (expression result) created in a loop, or conditionally add a value in a loop. Loops themselves are non-fractionable in the loop expression itself (at least in languages I'm aware of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i use .times for floats?

You can't. There is no `Float#times` method, as you can see [in the documentation of `Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html) and also in the error message.

> (If It is even possible....)

No, it is not possible, and this has nothing to do with Ruby or even with programming in general. Repeating something "a half times" or "a fractional number of times" is non-sensical.

Comment: Well then is there an alternative?!?!?

Comment: No, it is not possible, and this has nothing to do with Ruby or even with programming in general. Repeating something "a half times" or "a fractional number of times" is non-sensical.